# Memory location of a const reference

Tags: c++, reference, constants

I have the following C++ code, and I'm running g++ (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0:

```
#include <iostream>

const int& getConst() {
  int x = 10;
  printf("x ptr: %p\n", &x);
  const int &y = 10;
  printf("y ptr: %p\n", &y);
  return y;
}

int main() {
  int start = 0;
  printf("start ptr: %p\n", &start);
  const int &t = getConst();
  printf("t: %d\n", t);
  printf("t ptr: %p\n", &t);
  int end = 0;
  printf("end ptr: %p\n", &end);
  return 0;
}
```

And the output of this code is as follows:

```
root@78600f6683dd:/home/test/question# ./a.out
start ptr: 0x7ffdcd2381f8
x ptr: 0x7ffdcd2381c8
y ptr: 0x7ffdcd2381cc
t: 10
t ptr: 0x7ffdcd2381cc
end ptr: 0x7ffdcd2381fc
```

There are two things I'm confused about the result:

1. The memory location of `start` and `end` within the function `main()` are 0x7ffdcd2381f8 and 0x7ffdcd2381fc respectively. The memory locations of variables of `main` function are ascending. The main function calls `getConst()` function, but the location of variables within the function `getConst()` are 0x7ffdcd2381c8 and 0x7ffdcd2381cc, which are both descending comparing to variables within the `main()` function. Since `main` functions calls `getConst()` function, shouldn't location of `getConst()` be on top of the stack to `main()`?
2. Within `getConst()` function, `y` is a const reference to 10. As far as I understand it, the procedure is that, a *temporary int variable* is created with a value of 10, and y `references` to it. As seen in the output of the program, both `y` and `t` point to the same memory location. However the *temporary variable* is a variable defined in stack, shouldn't it be cleaned up after `getConst()` function returns? If so, how can `t` still get the correct value?

Comment: *"shouldn't location of getConst() be on top of the stack to main()?"* - it is on top of the stack. However you seem to have a wrong assumption that top of the stuck implies ascending addresses. Typically stack grows down. *"how can t still get the correct value"* - it doesn't get correct value, your program has undefined behavior.

Comment: You're returning a reference to an automatic temporary object, so using `t` in `main` has undefined behaviour. ( Note that a reference does not necessarily have any storage at all, and there is no way to determine the location of that storage even if it exists.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has undefined behaviour as it is returning a reference to a temporary variable so anything could happen.

However what is actually happening is probably that the returned reference is basically a pointer, the memory pointed to is no longer valid but the pointer itself is just a number so it is unsurprising that you are able to print its value. Printing the value of the reference will probably work as the runtime doesn't "clean up" deallocated stack memory, that would be a waste of time, when the memory is re-used it will be re-initialised. If you call a new function containing uninitialised variables it wouldn't be surprising if they also have the same values as set in `getConst`. This of course is all undefined behaviour.

Traditionally heap memory grew up from the bottom of the memory and stack grew down from the top, when the two met your program was out of memory. With modern virtual memory schemes this isn't literally the case any more but the stack is still generally a fixed size block of memory which is used from the end back to the front so it is not unusual for new stack allocations to have lower addresses than old ones. This is what makes overflowing stack variables so dangerous, you aren't overwriting unused memory you are actually overwriting variables earlier in the stack.

Comment: Another possibility is that the compiler has created a static const int variable in the data section of the executable, and y is referencing this.  Of course this is all attempting to reason about a program with UB, which is an exercise in futility.